# find specific patern in text using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

my string is

```
'21,300 32,709 30,391 29,901 22,270 31,201 31,199 27,806 23,210 28,418 28,940 32,496 16.9%'
```

how can I find all number but 16.9%??

I used

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+,*\d*(?!%)')
```

but It was not work.

thanks!

Comment: `'\d+,\d+(?!%)`

Comment: Must the regex work only on this exact string? All numbers to match contain a comma; is that required? Only the last one has a fraction and a percent sign; is that always the case? (If it is, split on spaces and discard the last item.)

Comment: Too vague.  What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with those pattern examples:

```
import re

a = '21,300 32,709 30,391 29,901 22,270 31,201 31,199 27,806 23,210 28,418 28,940 32,496 16.9%'

final = re.findall(r'(\d+)[,\s]', a)
# Or:
# final = re.findall(r'(\d+)[^\d\.%]', a)
```

Both will output:

```
print(final)

['21', '300', '32', '709', '30', '391', '29', '901', '22', '270', '31', '201', '31', '199', '27', '806', '23', '210', '28', '418', '28', '940', '32', '496']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import re

a = '21,300 32,709 30,391 29,901 22,270 31,201 31,199 27,806 23,210 28,418 28,940 32,496 16.9%'

re.findall(r'\d+.\d+%', a)
```

This regex will catch the percentage you want. Basically, i'm catching everything with '%' with one or more digits, separated by dot '.'